# There is seven methods in the object type, but i can just see four methods. Why?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The object class defines the methods shown in this Table:
[image: object methods]

And then i can see some of these methods when i create a class:

[image]

Since all other types are derived from object; i have to see all of the methods in object. There is seven methods in the object type, but i can just see four methods. Why?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to distinguish between static methods and instance methods.  Your IntelliSense window only shows the instance methods since you started typing a statement that uses an object.  Type `object.` to see the static ones.

Answer (score 4):

You do not see [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) methods (`Finalize()` and `MemberwiseClone()`) in that list because these methods can only be invoked from members of a subclass of `Object` (such as `A`), not from `Main()`.

In addition, as Hans says, static members [are not accessible from an instance](http://davesquared.net/2008/07/why-cant-i-access-static-members-from.html), so they are not shown either.

Comment: Can you explain more about protected methods that why i can't see them ?! how can i access Finalize() in A class?

Comment: @Mesut, you could call it from any instance method of `A` (constructors and property getters/setters included). However, `Finalize()` is not a good example because it is not meant to be called from your own code (it's meant to be overridden in your classes and called by the framework, and C# does not even allow you to override it, preferring destructors).

Answer (score 4):

Protected methods are only visible to child classes and static method can not be accessed from instance.

There are two `Equals` method. One of these are static. 
`MemberwiseClone` is a protected method. You can not see that here.
`ReferenceEquals` is a static method. And `Finalize` is a protected method.